# How to solve SPOJ : SCALE using binary search?

Tags: algorithm, scale, dynamic-programming, binary-search, brute-force

http://www.spoj.com/problems/SCALE/
I am trying to do it using recursion but getting TLE.
The tags of the problem say BINARY SEARCH.
How can one do it using binary search ?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: I think the tags are wrong: neither brute force, nor binary search is applicable (or at least, there's a great solution that's neither brute force nor binary search).

Comment: The tags are given on spoj.....people have done it using either brute force or binary search :D

Comment: The answer you accepted doesn't use binary search or brute force.

Comment: Now since I have understood the solution, I don't think it can be done using binary search..basically the tags are wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to notice here is that if you had **two** weights of each size instead of one, then the problem would be quite trivial, as we we would only need to represent `X` in its base `3` representation and take corresponding number of weights. For, example if `X=21` then we could take two times `P_3` and one time `P_2`, and put those into another scale.

Now let's try to make something similar using the fact that we can **add to both scales** (including the one where `X` is placed):

1. Assume that `X <= P_1+P_2+...+P_n`, that would mean that `X <= P_n + (P_n-1)/2` (easy to understand why). Therefore, `X + P_(n-1) + P_(n-2)+...+P_1 < 2*P_n`.

> **(*)** What that means is that if we add some of the weights from `1` to `n-1` to same scale as `X`, then the number on that scale still **does
>   not have `2` in its `n`-th rightmost digit (either 0 or 1).**

From now on assume that `digit` means a digit of a number in its `base-3` representation (but it can temporarily become larger than 2 :P ). Now lets denote the total weight of first scale (where `X` is placed) as `A=X` and the other scale is `B=0` and our goal is to make them equal (both `A` and `B` will change as we will make our progress) . 
Let's iterate through all digits of the `A` from smallest to largest (leftmost). If the current digit index is `i` and it:

1. Equals to `0` then just ignore and proceed further
2. Equals to `1` then we place weight `P_i=3^(i-1)` on scale `B`.
3. Equals to `2` then we add `P_i=3^(i-1)` to scale `A`. Note that it would result in the increase of the digit `(i+1)`.
4. Equals to `3` (yes this case is possible, if both current and previous digit were `2`) add `1` to digit at index `i+1` and go further (no weights are added to any scale).

Due to `(*)` obviously the procedure will run correctly (as the last digit will be equal to `1` in `A`), as we will choose only one weight from the set and place them correctly, and obviously the numbers `A` and `B` will be equal after the procedure is complete.

2. Now second case `X > P_1+P_2+...+P_n`. Obviously we cannot balance even if we place all weights on the second scale.

**This completes the proof and shows when it is possible and the way how to place the weights to both scales to equalise them.**

**EDIT**:

`C++` code which I successfully submitted on SPOJ just now https://ideone.com/tbB7Ve

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is quite trivial. The idea is the same as @Yerken's answer, but expressed in a bit different way:

- Only the first weight has a mass not divisible by 3. So the first weight is the only one has effect on balancing `mod 3` property of the 2 scales:

  - If X mod 3 == 0, the first weight must not be used
  - If X mod 3 == 1, the first weight must be on scale B (the currently empty one)
  - If X mod 3 == 2, the first weight must be on scale A
- Subtract both scales by weight(B) --> solution doesn't change, and now weight(A) is divisible by 3 while weight(B) == 0
- Set X' = weight(A)/3 and divide every weights Pi by 3 ==> Solution doesn't change, and now it's the same problem with N' = N-1 and X' = (X+1)/3

pseudo-code:

```
listA <- empty
listB <- empty
for i = 1 to N {
  if (X == 0) break for loop; // done!
  if (X mod 3 == 1) then push i to listB;
  if (X mod 3 == 2) then push i to listA;
  X = (X + 1)/3;  // integer division
}
hasSolution <- (X == 0)
```

C++ code: http://ideone.com/LXLGmE

Comment: yup this is correct, though the only downside it doesn't explicitly displays why there should exist a certain constraint on `X`, hence doesn't explicitly show when solution exists. My solution comes from a more of a math point of view (which is my background :P )

Comment: I did mention in the pseudo code that a solution exists if (and only if) X = 0 after some steps, and it's obvious because then the scales are balanced with both = 0